# DAG not running simultaneously

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

We have one DAG which used to work pretty well.
We later automated the process and ran the same DAG file using different threads 4-8 times almost simultaneously. It is throwing an error that says it is duplicate.
How to make it unique so that all the DAG calls are successful?

Comment: Why don't you just change the dag id and have 4 copies of it running simultaneously?

Comment: We can't as we read from a standard configuration. We resolved it using some unique run_id.